# Operation on specific part of image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, filter, computer-vision

I want to play with the part of the image outside the circle , i want to put some algorithms on image area which is outside the rectangle , Can i do this task and how can i do it , which way i need to follow

[image]

And can I apply the same functionalities without drawing rectangle on the image ? mean to say not to draw the rectangle on image and leave that area for further operations , just mention its angle without drawing it

Comment: Define a mask to that area and do operations you want. Finally replace the area with your part inside the rectangle.

Comment: how to perform the replacing task ?

Comment: Tell one operation you intend to do on that.

Comment: giving the other area blue color

Comment: which language? Python or C++?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK C++ language

Comment: Create a full blue image with same size of input image, then copy the area inside rectangle to the exact position on to blue image. (may be by pixel-by-pixel)

Comment: and what if i want it to multicolor , light colors ? and do you mean that i need to corp the area of rectangle and patch it to the new image ?

Comment: I think so. First try it and if any issue come up, explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solution can be found [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31132/operation-on-specific-part-of-image/?answer=31139#post-id-31139) given by the @haris

Solution :

1. Draw your rectangle to new binary image with thickness=CV_FILLED
2. Invert above binary image and create mask for your interested region.
3. Copy the source to new Mat and perform your operation.
4. Finally copy the processed image to your source image using the same mask.

I don't know what process you are going to do, and if it not use the neighbor pixel like filter, the above may work fine.

Edit:

While doing filter operation using above method, the black region in the mask boundary will also consider as a neighbor, so better approach is

1. Create mask using your Rect.
2. Copy source to new Mat using above mask((the part you need to exclude).
3. Process the entire source.
4. Later copy back the region of exclusion to processed image using above mask.